How to define a model within another model
I am trying to define a model Toto within another model Example1. I know this is not Best Practices, but Toto is purely meant for this specific model Example1 and I don't want to see it in my package browser.
Basically, I would like to end up with something like:
model Example1
    Toto toto;
    [...]
    model Toto
        [...]
    end Toto;
end Example1;

Is it somehow possible?

Yes, almost exactly like you did it. Just fix the syntax errors and move the model into a protected section:
model Example1
    Toto toto;
    // ....
protected
    model Toto
      // ...
    end Toto;
end Example1;


For clarification of the logic in Dymola: A "public model Toto" shows up in the package browser so that you can create the "Toto toto" in the same way as other components (drag'drop from package browser). If Example1 is read-only then the local model will not show up.

Thank you Marco for this elegant solution!
@Hans Olsson: I did not fully understand your comment. Could you please elaborate?


For your original case you can create "Toto toto" by just dragging in "Toto" to the diagram layer of "Example1". 2. If you make "Example1" read-only (by making the file read-only and reloading it, or by selecting "Lock" in the context menu of Example1 in the package browser) then Toto is no longer shown in the package browser.


OK thank you, I have just understood that I could use public instead of protected as part of the solution, hence the "hiding" technique that you proposed.
